# Triggering an event from a select to a function in a backbone view

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I've tried looking around, but I probably haven't searched precise enough.
So basically I'm writing a web app that uses backbone.js

So my problem is that I'm trying to go back to a view to call a function.

So I have a template that contains a select with an ID of "sel".

I render that template in view A.

that select also has a onchange="callme()". (I use the jquery change(), this is just for simplicity sake)

view A has the function callme(), but when the the user clicks on it, console will say, callme undefined.

The problem is that callme() is assumed to be global, A.callme() doesn't work, since it's not that instance of it, this.callme() doesn't either because 'this' is the select statement, and the view isn't really there on the html page.

So.... what must I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your code instead of explaining what it does?

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe to your event directly from view and handle control event there.

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({ 

    events: {
        'change select': 'selectHandler'
    },

    selectHandler: function(event) {
       // do my stuff
    }

});
```

In this case in the `selectHandler` function `this` will be the context of current view, because Backbone using jQuery `$.proxy` for delegating execution of control handlers to the view itself. To get the control instance in the handler you need to use `$(event.target)` property which will return control object.

Also you don't need `onchange` attribute.

P.S. Your control should be in the control which is set to `el` property of Backbone view.

Comment: Ok, so that would trigger for all select changes. How would I have it so that I can have varying function calls? -- I basically need an equivalent to onchange for various select forms

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out on another stackoverflow question

Comment: You can easily specify different selector like: `'change select.myselect'`. In this case handler only fires for `select` control with css class `myselect`. You can use any jQuery selectors.